# Get an active route with react-router in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am creating a project using reactjs.In my application i am getting the active route using this:

```
this.context.router.isActive
```

but getting undefined, i am using the react-router 4.Earlier this was worked for me when am using the lower version of react-router.
Here is my code:

```
class NavLink extends React.Component {

    render() {


     console.log( this.context.router.isActive)
          let isActive = this.context.router.isActive(this.props.to, true);
           let className = isActive ? "active" : "";
        return(
            <li  className={className} {...this.props}>
               <Link {...this.props}/>
            </li >
        );
    }
}

NavLink.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
};
```

Answer (score 26):

The architecture has changed in react-router v4 and `this.context.router.isActive` is no longer supported.

In react-router-v4, you could instead of creating a NavLink yourself use the exposed `NavLink` component.

**[From the documentation:](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md)**

> **NavLink**
>
> A special version of the  that will add styling attributes to
>   the rendered element when it matches the current URL.
>
> ```
> import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
>
> <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
> ```

It also provides you an activeClassName prop:

> **activeClassName: string**
>
> The class to give the element when it is active. The default given
>   class is active. This will be joined with the className prop.
>
> ```
> <NavLink
>   to="/faq"
>   activeClassName="selected"
> >FAQs</NavLink>
> ```

**Why is this.context.router.isActive not supported:**

Here is an excerpt from a **[github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4793)** issue

Rendering a `<Route>` does not necessarily mean "only render when you match the current location". For example, it can be used inject the router variables from the context into a component as props.

In `<NavLink>`, the `<Route>` is using the children prop, which means that it will call the children function whether or not the route matches. If the match is null, then we know that it did not match.

If you would prefer not to use `<Route children>` in this way, React Router offers an imperative approach with the `matchPath` function. This is what `<Switch>es` and `<Route>s` use internally to match a location against a path.

If your component is not receiving the `Router` props, then you could inject it using the `withRouter` HOC

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

export class withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to style active router

import NavLink

```
import {  NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

```
<NavLink className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active-link' : 'link')} to="/home">Home</NavLink>
```

in style.css

```
.active-link {
  color: hsl(96, 82%, 35%);
}
```

customize the style looks more beautiful.

~cheers