# React Router v4.2 style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React router V4.2  does not get the visited style

```
const activeLink = {
   "color": "red"
} 
<Link to="/" activeStyle={activeLink}>
  All categories
</Link>
```

I have tried with  to, but no success

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693540/get-an-active-route-with-react-router-in-reactjs/47766816#47766816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Link`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component doesn't have `activeStyle`, but the [`NavLink`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) component does.

```
<NavLink
  exact
  to="/"
  activeStyle={{ color: "red" }}
>
  All categories
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that **Link** doesn't support this property.

You may want to try **NavLink**:

> **React Router Documentation**:
>   A special version of the  that will add styling attributes to
>   the rendered element when it matches the current URL

For more info: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, tnx 
 1. it must be  but not  
 2. exect={true} is mandatory