# How do I match a string with the the path in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application where I wanted to render some menus depending upon the path.

I have following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/Test/marks
```

Now from this URL I need to get the Test string only so that I can match that string with the array and then get the associated objects with that key.

I tried using the `useLocation` but it gives us the object and again I have to add a regex to get that name.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Have you try [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693540/get-an-active-route-with-react-router-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

> You can achive this using `useParams` hook

```
<Route path='/:id/marks' element={<Component/>}>
```

in Your component

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Component() {
  // Get the id param from the URL.
  let { id } = useParams();
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention the `useLocation` hook so I'll assume you are using `react-router` or `react-router-dom`. You can use the [`useMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match) hook to test a path pattern, and if there is a match a match object is returned. The match object has a `params` property that will have any path params available on it.

> ```
> declare function useMatch<
>   ParamKey extends ParamParseKey<Path>,
>   Path extends string
> >(
>   pattern: PathPattern<Path> | Path
> ): PathMatch<ParamKey> | null;
> ```

> ```
> interface PathMatch<ParamKey extends string = string> {
>   params: Params<ParamKey>;
>   pathname: string;
>   pattern: PathPattern;
> }
> ```

Example:

Test path: `"/Test/marks"`

```js
import { useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const match = useMatch("/:key/marks");
console.log(match?.params?.key); // "Test"
...
```

If the component that needs to access that part of the URL path is already rendered as part of the normal routing, e.g. on a route rendered on path `"/:key/marks"`, it could also just use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook directly to access the `key` path parameter.

Example:

```
<Route path="/:key/marks" element={.....} />
```

And in the route component on test path: `"/Test/marks"`

```js
const { key } = useParams(); // "Test"
```